# Error in installing the python library: pip install pyswarms

Tags: particle-swarm

I have stuck at this point when installed the Pyswarms package. I'm using the Python 3.0 version and executed through notebook. Following ways tried and ended up with "ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pyswarms'"

[The ways i have tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BccAP.png)

Early responses with solution are greatly appreciated.

Thanks

TRied the following....

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlew4.png)

Expectation: To get the best solution